# Hangfire recurring job causing null reference exeption

Tags: c#, blazor, hangfire, recurring

I'm new to using hangfire for recurring jobs, and when I'm using them they don't seem to do what I want them to do.
When I use `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Clear Files", () => ClearFiles(FileFilter.pathName), "*/10 * * * *");` it always causes a Null Reference Exception, which is weird because when I just call `ClearFiles(FileFilter.pathName);` it works just fine. What am I doing wrong / what do I have to do to get around this error?

Comment: What is `FileFilter.pathName`? What does `ClearFiles` do? Show us the code where the error happens and maybe we can help.

Comment: FileFilter.pathName is a string I'm getting from my database, and the error happens in the first line of my ' public async Task ClearFiles(string pathName) ' function where I try to compare that string to another one but it says FileFilter is null. But it works every other time I call it in this page, just not when i have it in the hangfire timer for some reason

Comment: I would be worried about `FileFilter.pathName` changing value when the background job starts because the `FileFilter object is captured.

Comment: @DavidG it's grabbing it from the database so I'm not sure what could be changing it.

Comment: But why not grab it from the database from inside the `ClearFiles` method? The problem passing it in is that it can change before you run the job.

Comment: How FileFilter.pathname is loaded from database , can you share that part.

Comment: I have a FileFilter.cs class with the namespace of common.db and each time a component is created it creates a new row in the database. I've binded all the values so if i want pathname from the database i use FileFilter.pathname and it will get it. @CodingMytra

Comment: @DavidG So instead of calling the function with parameters I would just call ClearFiles() inside the HangFire recurring job line, and then add a line inside the ClearFiles to get the value instead of passing it in?